# changing device with v4l2-ctl is not working

Tags: drivers, 13.10, input-devices, tv-tuner, video4linux

I have a **WinTV HVR 1900 TV tuner** runnning on **Ubuntu 13.10**, from which I would like to **capture S-VIDEO** input. The device is supported, based on LinuxTV. As is written [here](http://marksnotebook.com/PVR-150_capture), it seems that that kind of device defaults to the tuner input, and that a change of input is therefore needed. This is also supported by the fact that trying to read the output stream with VLC using terminal command

> cat /dev/video1 > test.mpg

and opening the resulting file does succeed in opening the stream, but since there is no signal I see only a black screen. I am quite sure that my system handles the device correctly, and

> /dev/video1

does indeed exist (my integrated webcam holds the video0 slot).

**My problem is that trying to change devices through terminal command**

> **v4l2-ctl -d 1**

**as exposed [here](http://www.ivtvdriver.org/index.php/V4l2-ctl) yields no error, but seems to do nothing.**

Can anyone please help me here?

### Terminal session:

```
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl -I
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl -d 1
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl -I
Video input : 0 (Camera 1: ok)
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl -n
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUMINPUT
    Input       : 0
    Name        : Camera 1
    Type        : 0x00000002
    Audioset    : 0x00000000
    Tuner       : 0x00000000
    Standard    : 0x0000000000000000 ()
    Status      : 0x00000000 (ok)
    Capabilities: 0x00000000 (not defined)
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl --info
Driver Info (not using libv4l2):
    Driver name   : uvcvideo
    Card type     : 1.3M HD WebCam
    Bus info      : usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.3
    Driver version: 3.11.7
    Capabilities  : 0x84000001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps   : 0x04000001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I made it...
In a single line:

```
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video1 -i 2
Video input set to 2 (s-video: ok)
raoul@raoul-EasyNote-LS11HR:~$ cat /dev/video1>test.mpg
```

although I do not quite understand what difference it makes from the input I previously posted... it would seem that one needs to define the input type at the same time as the device switch.